# If the sum $\sum_{x=1}^{100}x!$ is divided by $36$, how to find the remainder?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> If the sum $$\sum_{x=1}^{100}x!$$ is divided by $36$, the remainder is $9$.

But how is it?

[THIS](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14436029#14436029) said me that problem is $9\mod 36$, but how did we get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $6!$ is already divisible by $36$.

Comment: It means that I can go as $1!+2!+3!+4!+5!$ divided by 36 gives remainder 9 and it is the same for $1!+2!+\dots+100!$, right? But, I have this question: how can we add remainders? I. e. how can we go as $9+0+0+\dots+0$?

Comment: When I divide 5 by 3 I get remainder 2 & when i divide 8 by 3 i get 2 but when i divide 5+8=13 by 3, i get only 1 so how can i add remainders?

Comment: Remainders are additive. If you get more than 36, it wraps around again. What you have is
1+2+6+24+12+0+...=45=9 (mod 36).

Comment: @Sush: You can add remainders, but you might need to take more remainders. In your example, 5 has remainder 2, 8 has remainder 2, so 5 +8 has the same remainder as 2 +2, which has remainder 1. In symbols $(3x+2) + (3y+2) = 3(x+y+1) +1.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson, THANK YOU so much sir! This is the best explanation I have got ever! Now I think I will be less confused with remainders!

Comment: You are welcome. I hope so.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to find the smallest positive integer $x$ such that $36|(x!)$
as $(m!)| (n!)$ for $m\le n$

if $36|(x!), 36$ will divide $y!$ for all $y\ge x$

Here $m,n,x,y$ are assumed to be positive integers

Now, by inspection, $\displaystyle5!=120\equiv12\pmod{36},\implies 6!=6\cdot120\equiv6\cdot12\equiv0\pmod{36}$

Answer (score 3):

One should consider that numbers written in a base are a series of remainders, so for example, 1957 gives 195 remainder 7, and 195 gives 19 remainder 5, and 19 is 1 remainder 9.  So 1957 is 1 re 9 re 5 re 7.  Adding remainders is then like adding the last n places of a base.

For $n$!, we have all factorials 6! or larger, are multiples of 36, so it's just a matter of adding the first 5 (1+2+6+24+120 = 153), and dividing this by 36 (4 remainder 9).  It's only the 9 we want.