# How to evaluate this infinite sum? $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin \frac{n!\pi}{720} =$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin \frac{n!\pi}{720} =$

I tried playing around with the $e$ based definition of $sin$ and the series based definition, but couldn't solve it. All I got is that it's convergent.

Comment: Just curious, how did you prove it was convergent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINT:

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723011/if-the-sum-sum-x-1100x-is-divided-by-36-how-to-find-the-remainder/723066#723066) idea,

As $\displaystyle 6!=720\implies720|(n!)$ for $n\ge6$

$\displaystyle\implies \sin\frac{n! \pi}{720}=0$ for $n\ge6$

Comment: That seems much more like the answer than a hint.

Comment: Oh dear lord, how on Earth did I miss that.. Thanks and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, sorry for the typo. Thanks for your observation.

Comment: Nice work spotting that!

Answer (score 4):

Try computing the first few terms of the series: in fact, make sure you compute at least six of them, and probably a few more than that.  There is something sneaky going on here that will make the infinite sum easy to compute.

**Added**: Don't feel too bad about missing the trick: [wolfram alpha didn't see it either.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+sin%28+n!+%2a+Pi%2F720%29+from+1+to+infinity) This seems to show a certain "lack of insight" from the computational knowledge engine...

Comment: +1 Interesting bit about WA. I tested this with my (legal:-)) copy of Mathematica 9.0. I guess it is needless to say that the outcome was the same.

Comment: @Jyrki: it's explanation is also amusing: "The ratio test is inconclusive."  I suppose that's technically true, but...

Comment: LOL. Mathematica 9.0 spake `Sum::div : Sum does not converge.`